# Trace Function Not Returning XmlList.length in As3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm looking to populate an array with bitmapdata based on some xml I load.  The problem I'm having is I can't seem to get the length of my XMLList...

```
var path:String = "http://mydomain.com/";

var bDataArray:Array = new Array();

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(path + "includes/categoryOutput.php"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addXML);

function addXML(e:Event):void{
    var list:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var urlList:XMLList = list.image;
    trace(urlList.length); // <-- should trace list length but traces nothing
    for each(var img:XML in urlList){
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(img));
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addBData);

    }

}
function addBData(e:Event):void
{
    bDataArray.push(e.target.content.bitmapData);
}
```

The xml is fine, I can even trace the list `trace(list);` and come back with my data.  I just need to get that list length so that adding my bitmaps can start when my array is fully populated.

Thanks in advance for any input.
-Jascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with xml you have to use length() as a function not as a property

```
trace(urlList.length());
```